Diagram 4.3.3.2, I, in "Catégories Tannakiennes" by S. Rivano
$\require{AMScd}\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$In Catégories Tannakiennes by N. Saavedra, chapter I, diagram 4.3.3.2, he claims (as far as I can tell) that the following diagram commutes:
$$\begin{CD} F(X^{\vee} \otimes Y) @>>> F(\underline{\Hom}(X,Y))\\
@AcAA @VF_{X,Y}VV\\
F(X^{\vee}) \otimes F(Y)\\
@VF_{X,\mathbf{1}} \otimes \mathrm{id}VV @VVV\\
F(X)^{\vee} \otimes F(Y) @>>> \underline{\Hom}(FX,FY)
\end{CD}$$
Here, we assume that $F$ is a tensor functor between rigid tensor categories,
where $F_{X,Y}$ is the induced map coming from $F(\text{ev})$ (suppressing the natural isomorphism $c$ coming from $F$ as a tensor functor) under the natural isomorphism  $\Hom(F(\underline{\Hom}(X,Y)) \otimes F(X),F(Y)) \simeq \Hom(F(\underline{\Hom}(X,Y)),\underline{\Hom}(FX,FY))$, and $F_{X,\mathbf{1}}$ has the obvious interpretation from this.
As far as I can see (I don't know much French), N. Saavedra gives no explanation for the commutativity of this diagram. He later (5.2.2, I) shows that $F_{X,\mathbf{1}}$ is an isomorphism, and since all the other maps in the diagram above are isomorphisms, it then easily follows from the commutativity of the above diagram that $F_{X,Y}$ is an isomorphism.
Unless I am mistaken, the horizontal maps are the isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{C}'$ (source and target of the functor $F$), coming from the isomorphism $X^{\vee} \otimes Y \cong \underline{\Hom}(X,Y)$.
So my question is basically how to see that this diagram commutes (my end goal is really to understand why $F_{X,Y}$ is an isomorphism).
Comment: note that in the above diagram, there is only one arrow $F_{X,Y}$ on the right, I just don't know how to write it as one arrow in AMScd.
I asked a similar question (not precisely the same) at MSE a while ago (Tensor functors on rigid categories.), but I had some trouble understanding the explanation given there (for example, I don't really know what an adjunction-diagram is).
Any clarification would be most helpful.
Edit: As per D. Rydhs comment, the horizontal maps are not neccessarily isomorphisms, since we are not assuming that we are in a rigid category. Furthermore, as D. Rydh points out, S. Rivano claims this follows as a special case of diagram 4.3.3.1 in S. Rivano (take $(X_1,Y_1) = (X,\mathbf{1})$ and $(X_2,Y_2) = (\mathbf{1},Y)$).

MathJax note: MathJax doesn't eat whitespace as aggressively as TeX does, so the ending $ of a "preamble" command like $\require{AMScd}$ must appear immediately adjacent to the first character of the post, or the post will start with spurious white space (in your case, blank lines).  I edited accordingly.  (By the way, the reason that you don't know how to make one long arrow with AMScd is because it's one of the many things that AMScd can't do.)

Thanks @LSpice, it was also my suspicion that it was not really possible (I checked Milnes documentation about AMScd Milnes Guide to AMScd).

Two comments: (1) In Section 4, the categories C and C' are not assumed to be rigid so the horizontal maps are not necessarily isomorphisms. (2) Diagram 4.3.3.2 is, as Saavedra Rivano mentions, a special case of diagram 4.3.3.1 (take $(X_1,Y_1) = (X,1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2) = (1,Y)$).

Honestly, Daniël's answer is as detailed as can be. I don't know what an "adjunction-diagram" is either; that term is not used in his answer. Do you mean you don't know how his first diagram relates to his second diagram? If so, you should convince yourself that the commutativity of these two diagrams is equivalent if $L \dashv R$ (hint: use the naturality of the $\mathrm{Hom}$-isomorphism).

Thanks for both of your inputs; a comment to Naim. I guess I am confused (in the answer I referenced) by:
$$
FX\otimes F(X^\vee\otimes Y)\cong FX\otimes F(X^\vee)\otimes FY\cong F(X\otimes X^\vee)\otimes FY\xrightarrow{F\varepsilon_X\otimes FY}FY,
$$
since I think it should really be:
$$
FX\otimes F(X^\vee\otimes Y)\cong FX\otimes F(X)^{\vee} \otimes FY\cong F(X\otimes X^\vee)\otimes FY\xrightarrow{F\varepsilon_X\otimes FY}FY$$ if one thinks about what $FX \otimes \gamma$ does. Perhaps I am mistaken.

@NaïmFavier and yes, I did mean why the first diagram commutes if the second does. Let me think more about the diagram you sent me.

Note that "S. Rivano" is actually "N. Saavedra Rivano", or simply "N. Saavedra".

Here is a direct argument for showing that $F_{X,Y}$ is an isomorphism. One can argue that $F[X, Y]$ and $[FX, FY]$ are both representing objects for the functor $\mathcal{C}'(- \otimes FX, FY)$, and furthermore the universal element for $F[X, Y]$ is the map $F(\mathrm{ev}_{X,Y}) : F[X,Y] \otimes FX \to FY$.
By the general theory of representable functors, if $(A, a : \mathcal{D}(-, A) \cong G)$ and $(B, b : \mathcal{D}(-, B) \cong G)$ are representations of the same presheaf $G$, then by the full faithfulness of the Yoneda embedding there is a unique isomorphism $i : A \cong B$ such that $\mathcal{D}(-, i) = b^{-1} \circ a$. Explicitly, the forwards map $i : A \to B$ is given by $b^{-1}(a(\mathrm{id}_A))$, where $a(\mathrm{id}_A)$ is the universal element for $A$.
Returning to our rigid categories, we find that the natural isomorphism $$b : \mathcal{C}'(-, [FX,FY]) \cong \mathcal{C}'(- \otimes FX, FY)$$ is just the tensor-hom adjunction isomorphism, and thus the isomorphism $i : F[X,Y] \to [FX,FY]$ is given by the adjoint of the map $F(\mathrm{ev}_{X,Y})$, which is exactly $F_{X,Y}$.

EDIT: maybe this answer won't satisfy you because we still have to show that $F(\mathrm{ev}_{X,Y})$ works as a universal element. This still probably involves an annoying diagram.
